# C++, std::list, assignment, inheritance

Tags: c++, inheritance, assignment-operator, stdlist

```
class A, B;
class A {
    public:
        A& operator= ( const A &rhs ) { return *this; }
};
class B: public A {
    public:
        B& operator= ( const A &rhs ) { return *this; }
};
A a;
B b;
std::list < A > aa;
std::list < B > bb;
a = b; // works
b = a; // works
// aa = bb; // fails
// bb = aa; // fails
```

How do I get bb = aa to work?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What you're missing here is that even though `A` and `B` are related types, `std::list<A>` and `std::list<B>` are actually unrelated types (other than both saying `list`). As such you can't use copy assignment to assign between them.

However, assuming that you're ok assigning the types `A` and `B` to each other using their assignment operators, you can use `list`'s `assign` method to copy the range of iterators:

```
aa.assign(bb.begin(), bb.end());
bb.assign(aa.begin(), aa.end());
```

Answer (score 4):

You can do this with a [`copy`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/copy/) and a [`back_inserter`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iterator/back_inserter/):

```
std::copy(aa.begin(), aa.end(), back_inserter<list<B>>(bb));
```

but under the condition that the target element (here B) can be constructed from the source element (here A). So here, you'd need a B constructor based on an A object.

[Online demo](http://ideone.com/n0rgVy)

Note: If you don't have the constructor needed for the copy in the target class, but you have some other way to build a target object from the source, you can consider using [`std::transform()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/transform/)

By the way, attention: `a=b` works, but might result in [slicing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_slicing).

Comment: What about just using `std::list::assign(iter, iter)` instead of the copy-inserter pattern?

Comment: Excelllent ! I falsely assumed the range had to be a list of the same type (and in addition I love inserters).  You should provide this answer, so that we can upvote ! .

Answer (score 3):

That you can assign a object of type `A` to an object of type `B` does not mean that holds for `list<A>` and `list<B>` as well.

Instead of you can use `std::copy`:

```
std::copy(bb.begin(), bb.end(), std::back_inserter(aa)); // instead of aa = bb
```

---

EDIT: in order to use that you either have to call `aa.resize(bb.size())` first, or better use a `back_inserter` as noted by @Christophe.

---

You should be clear about what you're doing here: it's either slicing (`A = B`) or assigning a non-final class (`B = A`). In order to avoid that, you should work with pointers and use the clone pattern.

Answer (score 2):

As far as the compiler is concerned `std::list<A>` and `std::list<B>` are disjoint types. This makes sense if you consider that `std::list` has internally allocated memory for `A` objects. Trying to assign `B` objects into that space could be disasterous.

Imagine, for example, that B has an extra property. Now, if you're trying to store a `B` into memory large enough for an `A`, it will likely not fit. Similar logic can be used to see why the other direction also fails: if you store an `A` into space for a `B`, the compiler expects that the extra property of the `B` it believes to be at that space is valid. If you assigned an `A` though, that space has who-knows-what in it.

If you want this assignment to be able to work, you're going to need to use some form of indirection. For example, you could use two `std::list<A*>` instances or two `std::list<std::shared_ptr<A>>` instances. This then works because a `B*` *can* be safely treated as an `A*`, at least assuming that the classes are properly written.

Comment: All of your points are valid. And that was my first thought when reading the question.  But since the author *did* define an assignment operator for `b=a`, working with `std::list<B>` is acceptable, even by value.

Comment: @geipel Right, but that doesn't really help him in assigning a `std::list<B>` to a `std::list<A>`. It would just mean that he could assign `A` instances into a `std::list<B>`. I assume his intent was to avoid anything for which he basically has to recreate the list to assign it.

Comment: True.  But fortunately, the original question was about getting `bb = aa` to work -- i.e. populating `std::list<B>` from `std::list<A>`. And that's is a valid question in this specific case.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think anyone actually tried to answer the question of how to do the assignment of `bb = aa;`

As previously mentioned, you cannot define an implicit cast or assignment operator for `std::list<B>` as a free operator.  But you do have two options. Both of them rely on subclassing this collection... which is OK as long as you don't allow any additional state.

Option #1, is to define `BB` as subclass of `std::list<B>` and `bb` would use these classes. (`BB` would get an additional assignment operator.)

Option #2, is to use a helper class, and is likely closer to your original intent. The helper class would be defined like the `BB` class described above, adding an implicit conversion operator back to `std::list<B>`.

A complete example follows:

```
class A {};

class B: public A {
public:
    B() = default;
    B( const A &rhs ) {} // Empty because A and B are not defined with any state.
    B& operator= ( const A &rhs ) { return *this; }
};

class BB : public std::list<B> {
public:
    BB() = default;
    BB(const std::list<A> &aa) { assign( aa.begin(), aa.end() ); }
    BB& operator= ( const std::list<A> &rhs ) { assign(rhs.begin(), rhs.end()); return *this; }
    operator std::list<B>() { return *this; }
};
// No new member variables or virtual methods are allowed.
static_assert( sizeof (std::list<B>) == sizeof (BB), "Bad derivation of std::list<B>" );


A a;
B b;

b = a; // works

std::list<A> aa;
std::list<B> bb;

BB helper;
bb = helper = aa;  // Option #2; bb is std::list<B>
```

Or you could just use `BB` directly:

```
BB bb = aa;        // Option #1; use bb just like std::list<B>
```